# phpseclib 2.0 generates different signature than any other library with same parameters

Tags: php, rsa, phpseclib

### Introduction

Hello, when signing a simple string `Hello World!` I get a signature that is different from any other library I'm using. I already double checked padding, algorithm, key pair, hash and input text.

### Code

```
<?php
/*
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha256",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

$resource = openssl_pkey_new ($config);
// Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
openssl_pkey_export($resource, $privKey);

// Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($resource);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];
echo var_dump($privKey) . "\n" . $pubKey;
*/
//require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;
$privatekey = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
";

$publicKey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
";

$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($privatekey);
$rsa->loadKey($publicKey);

$rsa->setHash('sha256');
$rsa->setMGFHash('sha256'); // Added to see if it made a difference. It made no difference
//$rsa->setSaltLength($sLen)
$rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1); // Added to see if it made a difference. It made no difference
$rsa->setSignatureMode(RSA::SIGNATURE_PKCS1);
$plaintext = 'Hello World!';

$signature = $rsa->sign($plaintext);


$rsa->verify($plaintext, $signature);
echo base64_encode($signature);
?>
```

### Output vs expected output

Output: `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`

Expected output: `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`

### Additional details

I'm sure I'm using:

- RSA
- SHA256
- PKCS1
- `Hello World!` as input text

You can check using openssl or [8gwifi RSA Signature/Generation & Validation](https://8gwifi.org/rsasignverifyfunctions.jsp) (make sure you paste the keys provided and change the signature algorithm to `SHA256withRSA`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. When loading the keys you can't load both. You need to load the one you need, do whatever operation you need and then load the other one for the next operation.

Comment: Hi I have same problem. I am not able to generate proper signature. I am using json text to generate. Can you guide me ?

Comment: Hello, hard to help you in comments. Open a new question, post your code and link it in a comment here so I can check it